# Does using a canvas element as texture source involve CPU/GPU sync and memory copy?

Tags: webgl, textures, chromium, webgl2

I have a `HTMLCanvasElement` with some pixels rendered on it. Now I want to upload its data to another framebuffer (via color attachment texture).

```js
gl.texImage2d(...otherArgs, canvasElement);
```

I'm wondering if this operation involves CPU/GPU sync and memory copy (from GPU memory to CPU memory and then to GPU memory again).

If it is implementation specific, my app will run in chromium (electron/edge webview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code today](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/refs/heads/main/Source/modules/webgl/WebGLRenderingContextBase.cpp#4287) there's various GPU-GPU fast-paths for canvas sources, including 2D canvases. So *today* ([since 2013](https://codereview.chromium.org/735623003)) there's no CPU readback for Canvas2D texImage sources in *chromium*.